# Access to the Dex is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

when i want to sync gradle i get this error:

```
Error:Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0
1.4.0 introduces a new Transform API allowing manipulation of the .class files.
See more information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api
```

When i click the link, i don't find any solution. 
Anyone have solution thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set your gradle version explicitly to 1.3.0 in dependencies section of build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Comment: I have tried to downgrade version. But the error same.

Comment: clear cache and let gradle sync and clean your build.

Comment: Isn't it `1.3.1` now?

Comment: but what if we actually want to use a newer version?

Comment: When I change the classpath and build the project the classpath get replaced with 2.0.xx.. any help ?

Comment: I wanna use InstantRun, so i just update the gradle and get this error. Do you have any solution ? no downgrade.

Comment: I guess the latest version is stable now. use 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in other answers, downgrade is one option. But, it is not a solution. As asked by [David Argyle Thacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/809069/david-argyle-thacker), what if we actually want to use a newer version (of gradle build tool)?

I was having same trouble while upgrading gradle tool version in one of my projects. So, I did following and voila, it worked.

1. Update all the libraries (dependencies from Google Play Services and Support libraries along with other SDKs used) to the max available version. If you are using NewRelic, then update to the latest version.
2. Add multiDexEnabled true to the defaultConfig in /app/build.gradle.

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```
3. Remove all the code you have previously written to get MultiDexing to work.
   For instance,

   - Remove the `afterEvaluate` block for MultiDex

     ```
     afterEvaluate {
         tasks.matching {
             it.name.startsWith('dex')
         }.each { dx ->
             if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                 dx.additionalParameters = []
         }
         dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'

         // this is optional
         //  dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex-classes.txt".toString()
         }
     }
     ```
   - Remove `multidex` dependency

     ```
     dependencies {
         ...
         compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
     }
     ```
   - Remove the code from `AndroidManifest.xml`

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             package="com.example.pcsalt.multidex">
         <application
                 ...
             android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
                 ...
         </application>
     </manifest>
     ```
   - If you are using custom Application class by extending android.app.Application, then remove `MultiDex.install(base);`

     ```
     @Override
     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
             super.attachBaseContext(base);
             MultiDex.install(base);
     }
     ```
4. Update the build tool version to `2.1.2` (highest stable version available at the time of writing) in /build.gradle

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
   ```
5. Gradle Sync the project, by clicking Sync now

Hope this helps.

http://www.pcsalt.com/android/solution-access-dex-task-now-impossible-starting-1-4-0

Comment: but what if we want multidex support?

Comment: @Harshad Above mentioned steps are to achieve multidex support in build tool greater than 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your gradle version to 1.3.0