# Changing gradle version from 1.4 to 1.3 not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I get the following error on adding a dependency,

> ```
> Gradle sync failed: Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0
>          1.4.0 introduces a new Transform API allowing manipulation of the .class files.
>          See more information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api
>          Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
> ```

Changing the version from 1.4 to 1.3 should fix this but somehow android studio still builds using 1.4 and throws the same error.

```
before: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0'

now : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

how can I force android studio to use 1.3 instead

steps taken without success:

- deleted .gradle under root/user/
- deleted .gradle under project
- reduced only instance of dependency to com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579192/access-to-the-dex-is-now-impossible-starting-with-1-4-0

Comment: is this "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1" present at your end.

Comment: Yes added "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1" in gradle.build file, I tried deleting the cache from .gradle directory but didn't work, anything else I need to remove

Comment: make sure all your gradle file contains same classpath :i.e  "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1"